# Why does my scroll function work with IDs but not classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, scroll

I'm trying to add (not replace) a class to multiple elements when scrolling down `10px`. I need to target multiple IDs in some HTML that I have **no way of changing**. These elements do share a few classes though, so I thought I could just target one of those instead.

When I use `getElementById`, it runs just fine and adds a class to a single ID. If I use `getElementsbyClassName` or `querySelectorAll` to target a class, it won't work.

This one works:

```
tabs = document.getElementById("intro");

scrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 10) {
  tabs.classList.add("scrollNav");
              }
  else {
    tabs.classList.remove("scrollNav");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunc);
```

This one doesn't:

```
tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("navTabs");

scrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 10) {
    tabs.classList.add("scrollNav");
  }
  else {
    tabs.classList.remove("scrollNav");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must loop over each element in the collection that `getElementsByClassName` returns.

Try:

```
tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("navTabs");

scrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 10) {
  [...tabs].forEach((tab) => {
     tab.classList.add("scrollNav");
  });
  }
  else {
   [...tabs].forEach((tab) => {
     tab.classList.remove("scrollNav");
    });
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunc);
```

According to MDN, getElementsByClassName returns an "HTML Collection" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection which on its own does not have a forEach method. You can use the spread syntax `...` to add each item in the collection into a new array `[]` which does have a forEach method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`. The `classList` attribute exists only on single elements. On the other hand, `getElementById` returns an element.

To change the class list of every element in the collection, you need to convert it into an array and then loop over every element in it. See below:

```js
tabs = [...document.getElementsByClassName("navTabs")];

scrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 10) {
    tabs.forEach(tab => tab.classList.add("scrollNav"));
  }
  else {
    tabs.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("scrollNav"));
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunc);
```

This code uses ES6; you could easily convert it to a more browser-compatible version.

Related resources:

- [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection): `document.getElementsByClassName("navTabs")`
- Singular [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element): `document.getElementById("intro")`
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax): `[...document.getElementsByClassName("navTabs")]`
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): `tab => tab.classList.add("scrollNav")`